# What would be the better algorithm for generating following result?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures, logic

We have a input of array having `n` numbers (non-zero) i.e.

```
input--> [a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, ...., aN] (not in order)
```

Now we want the output as

```
output--> Ai <= Aj >= Ak <= Al >= Am <= ....An.
```

i have written a code for this problem and it is quite fine but not optimized if i talk about time and space complexity then it must not be good solution.

```
function test(array){
    if(array && array.length){
        let newArray = [];
        array = array.sort();
        let m;
        if(array.length % 2){
            m = (array.length +1 )/2;
        }else{
            m = (array.length)/2;
        }
        newArray.push(array[m-1]);
        for(let i=1;i<=m;i++){
            if(array[m-1+i])
            newArray.push(array[m-1+i]);
            if(array[m-1-i])
            newArray.push(array[m-1-i]);
        }
        console.log(newArray);
        return newArray;
    }else{
        throw 'invalid argument';
    }
}

test([1,2,3,4]);
```

Please help me if you any idea to optimise like using no other variables(it will reduce space complexity). Thanks

Comment: Can you explain in words what you're trying to do? It's not entirely clear, I'm not sure what `Ai <= Aj >= Ak <= Al >= Am <= ....An.` means

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to sort the array.
Just do one pass over the array, and in each step fix only a[i], a[i+1].

Suppose a[1] <= a[2] >= a[3]...<= a[i-1] >= a[i]

Now, if a[i] <= a[i+1], continue by increasing i.

if a[i] > a[i+1], swap them.

Symmetrically, when i is even, if a[i] < a[i+1] swap a[i],a[i+1].

Comment: nope, this would be wrong! check with following: 
ip: 1, 6, 2 , 8, 10, 3

Comment: @ReturnZero {1,6,2,8,10,3} -> {1,6,2,10,8,3} -> {1,6,2,10,3,8}

Comment: Thanks, it is a nice solution .

Comment: @shukiavraham Symmetrically, when i is even, if a[i] < a[i+1] swap a[i],a[i+1]. this line making sense now : /

Answer (score 1):

Your current algorithm runs on `O(n log n)` time. The `.sort()` at the beginning takes `O(n log n)` time, while the `for` loop below it runs in `O(n)` time. So, one possible improvement would be to change the `sort` function to use counting sort instead (which has time complexity `O(n + k)`, where `k` is the range from the lowest number to the highest number). This will reduce the overall time complexity from `O(n log n)` to `O(n + k)`, which will be a significant improvement with larger sets:

```js
function countingSort(array) {
  const counts = array.reduce((a, num) => {
    a[num] = (a[num] || 0) + 1;
    return a;
  }, {});
  /*
  ok, maybe this is cheating
  return Object.entries(counts).reduce((arr, [num, occurrences]) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < occurrences; i++) {
      arr.push(Number(num));
    }
    return arr;
  }, []);
  */
  const sorted = [];
  const min = Math.min(...array);
  const max = Math.max(...array);
  for (let i = min; i <= max; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < counts[i]; j++) {
      sorted.push(i);
    }
  }
  return sorted;
}


function test(array){
    if(array && array.length){
        let newArray = [];
        array = countingSort(array);
        let m;
        if(array.length % 2){
            m = (array.length +1 )/2;
        }else{
            m = (array.length)/2;
        }
        newArray.push(array[m-1]);
        for(let i=1;i<=m;i++){
            if(array[m-1+i])
            newArray.push(array[m-1+i]);
            if(array[m-1-i])
            newArray.push(array[m-1-i]);
        }
        console.log(newArray);
        return newArray;
    }else{
        throw 'invalid argument';
    }
}

test([1,2,3,4]);
```

Counting sort performs best when there aren't large gaps between the numbers. If there *are* large gaps between the numbers, you could use [radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) instead, which also runs in linear time (but is a bit more complicated to code).

(if you *do* use the built-in `sort` function, though, make sure to sort numerically, with `.sort((a, b) => a - b)`, otherwise your resulting array will be sorted lexiographically, eg `[1, 11, 2]`, which is not desirable)

Answer (score 1):

This could be a better logic finally :-

```
    function optimizedSort(array) {
    if(array && array.length){
        let temp;
        for(let i=0;i<array.length;i++){
            if((i+1)%2){
                // i is odd

                if(array[i]>=array[i+1]){
                    temp = array[i];
                    array[i] = array[i+1];
                    array[i+1] = temp;
                }

            }else{
                // i is even

                if(array[i]<=array[i+1]){
                    temp = array[i];
                    array[i] = array[i+1];
                    array[i+1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        console.log('********',array);
        return array;
    }else{
        throw 'invalid argument';
    }
}
optimizedSort([1,2,3,4]);
```